# Hazelcast load data from RDBMS in client-server topology

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast.net

I am using client-server topology for hazelcast cache. I have multiple maps which I load eagerly using MapLoaders. When there is a cache miss- Maploader's load(key) method is called. The MapLoader.load(key) method seems to be executed by the partition thread, which means that all other operations on the partition are blocked until loading is done. A very common use case for the MapLoader is to load data from a DB, which arguably can take some time. So what is the best possible approach to take so that other operations on partition are not blocked when laod is taking place? Is there any other way to load missing data at runtime?(Hazelcast version : Hazelcast 4.0.3)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690689/loading-time-of-hazelcast-imap) that gives a few options.

`MapLoader.load(key)` only loads a single entry, but if the remote source is really slow or there are lots of cache misses it's going to mount up.

Another alternative to @mike-yawn 's answer would be to have a `Runnable` that fetches needed items from the database and writes them directly into the map. You can still have the `MapLoader.load(key)` as well, but the chances of cache miss are reduced if your fetcher code is good at predicting what entries will be needed.

If you don't cache 100% of the records, then a cache miss is inevitable. If it's punitively slow you could always return a Entry.Value that contains some sort of flag that it's a placeholder and launch a thread to do the actual load. Then your code has to deal with that placeholder and try again later -- noting that when it tries later the eventual result of the database query could be no record found.

Comment: Thanks @Neil Stevenson for your answer.  For the eager cache load, are there more options than maploader. Currently I am loading around 8 maps and it takes around 7.5 minutes.

Comment: Do you have timings for your `loadAllKeys()` and `loadAll(Collection<K>)` methods ? If the database is fundamentally slow, your best option is to avoid restarting.

Comment: There is another option but it's in the commercial edition.

Comment: For eager cache load, consider also using the Jet engine as a massively parallel ETL for Hazelcast. It can run as a standalone cluster (shut down once the cache is populated) or inside Hazelcast (you run Jet cluster instead of Hz cluster). Code samples: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/tree/master/examples#integration-with-hazelcast-imdg